# How to use 'UWidgetLayoutLibrary::GetMousePositionOnViewport(...)' in Unreal Engiene 4.26 C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I created simple class, who implemented AActor. In this class i want get mouse position in game-dispaly. I know, that i must included 'Blueprint/WidgetLayoutLibrary.h' in *.cpp-file and in method 'Tick' write the following:

```
FVector2D mousePosition = UWidgetLayoutLibrary::GetMousePositionOnViewport(GetWorld());
```

so that every tick to get mouse position...
BUT!!! I get an error:

```
 Worlds_constantes.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: ??뫪? ?? ??ࠧ??襭??? ???譨? ᨬ??? "__declspec(dllimport) public: static struct FVector2D __cdecl UWidgetLayoutLibrary::GetMousePositionOnViewport(class UObject *)" (__imp_?GetMousePositionOnViewport@UWidgetLayoutLibrary@@SA?AUFVector2D@@PEAVUObject@@@Z) ? ?㭪樨 "public: virtual void __cdecl AWorlds_constantes::Tick(float)" (?Tick@AWorlds_constantes@@UEAAXM@Z).
 C:\Users\user\Documents\Unreal Projects\Project_name\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-Project_name-6913.dll : fatal error LNK1120: ??ࠧ??襭??? ???譨? ??????⮢: 1
```

What to do? How to fix?

Comment: Linker error says UWidgetLayoutLibrary::GetMousePositionOnViewPort implementation can't be found. Post your Actor code?

Comment: It's very strange)) this is method was wrote not me, is system method from UE4 library) BUT thanks for ansver.

Comment: Did you include library for FVector2D? If not you could try, might help. Here is the include for this: `#include "Math/Vector2D.h"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have found the answer now, but this question has been bothering me for several days, so I decided to reply to you here, just add *"UMG"* in the specified position in *Project.build.cs*, maybe this question is too simple, there is almost no answer online.But for those who are just learning Unreal and C++, it is not known.

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore","UMG" });
```